# Real time typing in PyGame

Tags: python, text, pygame

I am trying to write a small piggybank program. I already have a window with some background and text but I need to add a functionality for the user to let him add money to the piggybank. When the user press "1" he can see the text "how much do you want to add?" and here is where my problem begins... It's my third day with programming ever and I don't even know what I am looking for. I want to to show in real time what amount user is typing. Any tips?

Here's my code so far (which I can understand :P)

```
    # wyświetlenie napisów
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comic sans MS", 15, bold=True) #ustawienie czcionki
    text = font.render("::Swinka 1.4::",False,(BLACK))
    screen.blit(text, [150,0])
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [0,20], [400,20], 3)
    text = font.render("Chlewik",False,(BLACK))
    screen.blit(text,[145,50])
    text = font.render("Aktualny Stan: " +stan_konta,False,(BLACK))
    screen.blit(text,[145,110])
    text = font.render("1. Nakarm mnie",False,(BLACK))
    screen.blit(text,[10,150])
    text = font.render("2. Dieta",False,(BLACK))
    screen.blit(text,[10,170])

    # obsługa klawiszy
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # ogólne wywołanie wciśnięcia klawisza
        if event.key == pygame.K_2: # naciśnięcie konktretnego przycisku, w tym przypadku "2"
            #screen.fill(PINK) # odświeżenie ekranu (wycyszczenie plus pomalowanie)
            screen.blit(background, [0,0])
            stan_konta = 0 # przypisanie początkowej wartości konta
            stan_konta=str(stan_konta) # zamiana z liczb na znaki
            plik = open("dane/amount.txt", "w") # zapisanie do pliku 
            plik.write(stan_konta)
            plik.close()
            text = font.render("Swinka pusta!",False,(BLACK))
            screen.blit(text, [185,170])
        if event.key == pygame.K_1:
            #screen.fill(PINK)
            screen.blit(background, [0,0])
            text = font.render("Ile mam zjesc?",False,(BLACK))
            screen.blit(text,[185,150])


    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please show us the code which you use to detect that the user has pressed "1": Edit the question, paste the code into it, select the pasted code and click on the "code" button above the editor (`{}`). That will convert it into "code".

Comment: Consider writing your code (including comments) in English. I understand if the output would be in your native language but the comments are for your eyes (and ours) only and should be transferable across geographical borders.. I don't speak chech/polish so i get confused by just looking at it :) Other than that, kudos for writing this on your 3:d day of programming..

Comment: @Torxed :) yea, sure I will do that. When I was first writing them I thought I will be the only person in the world reading them. I thought I will manage to do this program by myslelf. I was soooo wrong. If you have any tips regarding python and pygame or ideas what should I learn just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @Hanouk Worked with Pygame|Pyglet|wxPython and Python for years now, so i'll do what i can to help, however for this particular problem Bartlomiej have solved your issue i think. `else: self.text += chr(event.key)` would do the trick :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short example:

```
#creates a new string, that will store the character you have written
number_str = "" 

#create a new Font object that is used to render the string into a Surface object
font_renderer = pygame.font.Font("monospace", 15) 

while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0)) # fill the whole screen with a black color
    # create a new Surface object from a string, where the text is white.
    rendered_number = font_renderer.render(number_str, True, (255,255,255))

    #draws the created Surface onto the screen at position 100,100
    screen.blit(rendered_number, (100, 100))
    # updates the screen to show changes
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if pygame.KEY_0 < event.key < pygame.KEY_9: # checks the key pressed
                character = chr(event.key) #converts the number to a character
                number_str += str(character) #adds the number to the end of the string
```

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: `number_str` is a bad name for a variable that can only contain letters :-) Maybe you wanted `if pygame.KEY_O < event.key < pygame.KEY_9:`?

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of why this works, because the OP isn't familiar to programming this is probably almost as confusing as the code he/she's already written. `if event.type = pygame.KEYDOWN:` is the reason for why this is working, for each keypress you simply update a label (or font). Explain that and you surely deserve the win on this one.

Comment: @Torxed: Python doesn't allow assignment in an `if`; it's a typo (fixed).

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yea noticed my mistake but can't edit a comment after 5 minutes.. I ment to say say `==` :) I was referring to the fact that your code is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like what's explained in [this](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_text/text.html#edit-text-with-the-keybord) tutorial:

```
"""Edit text with the keyboard."""
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
 
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GRAY = (200, 200, 200)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 240))

text = 'this text is editable'
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
img = font.render(text, True, RED)

rect = img.get_rect()
rect.topleft = (20, 20)
cursor = Rect(rect.topright, (3, rect.height))

running = True
background = GRAY

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                if len(text)>0:
                    text = text[:-1]
            else:
                text += event.unicode
            img = font.render(text, True, RED)
            rect.size=img.get_size()
            cursor.topleft = rect.topright
    
    screen.fill(background)
    screen.blit(img, rect)
    if time.time() % 1 > 0.5:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, cursor)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```